# Significance of derivative in finding square free decomposition

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials, prime-factorization, gcd-and-lcm

If $gcd(f(x),`f(x))=1$ then f(x) is square free. But what is the reason behind taking derivative of f(x)? How one came to this conclusion?

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)=g(x)^2h(x)$ then by the product rule $$f'(x)=2g(x)g'(x)h(x)+g(x)^2h'(x)=g(x)\cdot(2g'(x)h(x)+g(x)h'(x))$$
so that $g(x)$ is a common factor of $f$ and $f'$

Comment: I am aware of this proof, I wanted to know just how they thought that they should chose derivative of a function to find a GCD. What is the link between factorization and derivatives.